# Styling not applied to dynamically added TextBlock content

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, textblock

I'm trying to add inlines to a text block using the code below. The text block's window uses a `Themes.xaml` file for styling, but when I add the runs dynamically, the styling does not get applied. Can you help me understand why?

```
foreach (string key in wrappingOptions.Keys)
{
  Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(new Run(key));
  string s = new string(wrappingOptions[key].ToCharArray());
  link.Click += (o, _) => tbIn.SelectedText = string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>",
    s, tbIn.SelectedText);
  InputLinksBlock.Inlines.Add(link);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hyperlink is a FrameworkContentElement class. It does not derive it's text display properties from the parent TextBlock. You explicitly need to set a default style for a Hyperlink using `<Style TargetType="Hyperlink">`.